# Axis of symmetry of equation $xy=1/3$

Tags: graphing-functions, symmetry

Why is $x=y$ an axis of symmetry of the figure described by $xy=1/3$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because if you interchange $x$ and $y$ the equation does not change.

Note that in general if $(a,b)$ is a point, then the point $(b,a)$ is the *reflection* of $(a,b)$ in the line $x=y$. If you have a more complicated equation, like $x^3+y^3=xy+25$ with the same property of being unchanged when $x$ and $y$ are interchanged, we will have the same phenomenon. Note that in this case the point $(1,3)$ is on the curve. Since $x$ and $y$ appear symmetrically in the equation, it is **automatic** that $(3,1)$ is also on the curve.

Comment: @ChrisEagle: Thank you, I had managed with a simple typo to make the whole answer meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

It is obvious, when you draw a picture:

[image]

(from [here](http://tinyurl.com/c8jby6h))

Answer (score 1):

Using the change of variables (rotation) $x=\frac{v-u}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $y=\frac{v+u}{\sqrt{2}}$, which sends $x=y$ to $u=0$, we get
$$
\frac13=xy=\frac{v^2-u^2}{2}\tag{1}
$$
Equation $(1)$ becomes
$$
v^2=u^2+\frac23\tag{2}
$$
Since we get the same values of $v$ for $u$ and $-u$, we see that $u=0$ ($x=y$) is an axis of symmetry.